# Samba domain controller auto assign group IDs

Tags: samba

I have successfully provisioned a Samba AD Domain Controller. I was able to join various Windows hosts to it and configure AD Users with roaming profiles. So far this works well.
Now I have created a group in AD "developers" and I want to provide a share on the file server where only the "developers" have full access, everybody else is denied access.

In Windows, I can happily assign the "developers" group full control over the share, but this is not respected by Samba. Instead, nobody has access to the share, unless I allow the "Domain Users" or "Domain Administrators". When I run

`getent group "MYDOMAIN\Domain Users"`

I get some meaningful information:

`MYDOMAIN\domain users:x:8324:`

on the other hand, when I run the same command for the "developers" group, I get nothing:

`getent group "MYDOMAIN\developers"`

So I believe this has to do with the fact that this group doesn't have a group ID assigned. When I run

`wbinfo -g`

I can see both groups, the "domain users" and the "developers", so the group definitely is created successfully. I have now manually assigned a group ID in the "Active Directory Users and Computers" GUI, under "Attribute Editor", "gidNumber". When I populate this attribute with a GID number, then everything works as intended.

So I now wonder if it is possible to have Samba automatically populate this GID number when a new group is created? otherwise I feel that this may be difficult as it could easily happen to assign duplicate group IDs by accident.